# UIButton not Blinking on Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton, created programmatically, inside a UIView (no other levels to the hierarchy). The button **does respond to the `touchUpInside` event properly**, but, for some reason, the text **isn't exhibiting its normal "blink" behavior when touched**. I'd like to get that back, if anyone knows what could cause this.

Other notes: I have `userInteractionEnabled = TRUE` and there are no custom animations in my code. Relevant instantiation code (UIColor names are from a custom category):

```
self.loginButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
self.loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor MPBlackColor];
[self.loginButton setTitle:@"LOG IN" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor MPGreenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Bold" size:24.0f];
```

Comment: Give it a title color for the highlighted state.

Comment: I never had to do so before, and unless I do some trial and error with the color choice, the effect doesn't seem to be the same... did this behavior change recently? 

Edit: when I drop a button onto a blank storyboard, it still blinks as I'm used to

Comment: Like I said, it's not quite the same effect, but it'll work. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your custom color for the normal state applies also for the highlighted state, unless you give it a separate color for the highlighted state. This is true of all button state related values.

Comment: Alternatively assign a tint color and not a title color!

Comment: Oh, another problem is that you threw away standard behavior when you created the button with alloc init. That is not how you make a button! Use buttonWithStyle and ask for a system button.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a color for both normal and highlighted button state. In Swift:

```
loginButton.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)
loginButton.setTitleColor(.green, for: .highlighted)
```

Note: the same logic applies to a blinking button with an image. You should set both `.normal` and `.highlighted` states